# Could not find artifact gnu.trove:trove:jar:3.0.3 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Tags: java, maven, trove4j

I'm trying to download gnu.trove library, I have this dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/gnu.trove/trove -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>gnu.trove</groupId>
    <artifactId>trove</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

But I get this error:

```
Could not find artifact gnu.trove:trove:jar:3.0.3 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```

Why?
Should I add some other repository in `pom.xml`? Right now I have this repository listed:

```
<repository>
  <id>jcenter</id>
  <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
  <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: the binary `gnu.trove:trove` is neither in maven central nor in the jcenter bintray repository. you will have to download and link the binary, or build it yourself using `mvn install`

Answer (score 1):

There is a note in [mvn search](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/gnu.trove/trove/3.0.3) `Note: this artifact it located at TU-Darmstadt repository (http://zoidberg.ukp.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/artifactory/public-releases/)`;

Maybe you shuld add this repository.

That's two ways for you to do this;
1.Open the `settings.xml` in `${Maven_Path}/conf/` and navigate to the `<mirrors>...</mirrors>`,then you can add the repository here(there may had some samples for help).
2.Edit you `pom.xml`,add repository in the tag `<repositories>`.
e.g:

```xml
<resposity>
<id>zoidberg-nexus</id>
              <name>Zoidberg Nexus</name>
              <url>http://zoidberg.ukp.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/artifactory/public-releases/</url>
              <releases>
                  <enabled>true</enabled>
              </releases>
</resposity>
```

Comment: I've seen that note, but I'm not sure how to include that `zoidberg` repo.

Answer (score 1):

try adding the repo from mvnRepository

```
 <repository>
      <id>mvnrepository</id>
      <url>http://mvnrepository.com/artifact</url>
  </repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.trove4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>trove4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```